# Threading in Objective-C: most efficient way for an update?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading

I have a CoreData application with dynamic data that is updated once a day via a server.

The update is handled in a seperate class and in the AppDelegate I write:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.updater = [[Updater alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [updater checkForUpdatesInContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
}
```

The `checkForUpdatesInContext` checks whether a day has passed or not and then does the updating process.

Now this way of course it would run on the main thread, and if an update is going on, the app would "freeze" until the update is done, which could take a while, since new objects are created and there's also images involved. So my idea was to run this on a background thread or on a second thread or whatever Objective-C offers.

My question: What would be the most efficient way to get `checkForUpdatesInContext` off the main thread and how to go about it? The apple docs are (as usual) somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the update operation to happen in a background thread isn't that tricky e.g.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateWithData:) withObject:data];

...

- (void)updateWithData:(NSData *)data {
    // I am now in a background thread
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

or if you are looking for the ability to cancel the background thread, read up on [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Your problem is going to be dealing with multithreading and CoreData :) You need to read [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). Basically, you need to make sure that your background thread doesn't use the same NSManagedContext (it must create a new one from the same NSPersistentStore) and doesn't pass NSManagedObjects between threads (i.e. only pass object IDs back to the UI thread, not the objects themselves).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.. I'll be sure to read that guide.

Can I pass the NSPersistentStore?

Comment: You seem to have dealt with multithreading and CoreData yourself before. My case is pretty simple: The update operation only gets data from the web and creates new objects and inserts them to the store, or fetches outdates objects from the store and deletes them. Is it possible to simply to pass to the update operation the NSPersistentStore and just delete and insert the needed objects in the store there? Or would there be major problems if a UI thread uses an object that is being deleted e.g. in a UITableView? If this is not easy to answer or is really laid out in the apple docs let me know

Comment: If you remove an object from the store and the ui thread then uses it, you're in trouble!

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to send that comment then! To deal with this, I don't delete objects, I just set a BOOL 'deleted' property on them to mark them as deleted - I just have to remember to not show the deleted ones on the UI (and next time the app starts up, I can delete them then before the UI gets chance to use them!)

Comment: Yep ok. that seems reasonable. I'll try this out tomorrow. Would you mind if I let you know (in another comment I guess :D) if I'd run into any problems? Feel free to say no..

Comment: Of course I don't mind! - if I didn't want to communicate, I wouldn't have answered your question ;) Good Luck!

Comment: Finally I got around to implement this thing.. now the first error I came across is "'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x19da00> was mutated while being enumerated" so I understand that in a set of pictures there was probably a picture added while a tableview was trying to fetch the object with said picture set.. basically.. I have 5 viewcontrollers, 3 of which are using a NSFRC with a tableview.. Is it impossible to fetch data during updates? (meaning while objects are added/deleted)

Comment: I think for my next response I'll just edit the question since it's marked as answered already anyways.. it's just really hard to read here .. sorry

Comment: You might want to pass a `copy` of the Set around instead of `retain`ing it in your view controllers properties ;) - see why here : http://vgable.com/blog/2008/11/14/prefer-copy-over-retain/

Comment: But the crash happened as I was scrolling a tableView.. so I wasn't holding an object as a variable.. or maybe I dont understand what you meant..? 

My "boss" just told me that I could simply add an alertView during the update so it doesn't get too complicated. but I'm really curious how one would achieve this. Seems like quite a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Web Service to retrieve your Data, you should use Asynchronous Calls with NSURLConnection with Delegate Methods

Alternatively you could look in to something like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which handles a lot of the pain of Asyncronous Calls and NSURLConnection. ASIHTTPRequest has excellent Documentation and an active Google Group. It will require experimentation to get right.

Comment: I edited my question in the first post, to make it more clear, sorry :-/